# mongodb, calculate result after mapreduce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

I have mapreduce function to group and calculate some field

```
map = %Q{
  function() {
    emit({ip: this.ip, campaign_id: this.campaign_id}, {total_count: 1, total_commission: this.commission, uniq_commission: 0});
  }
}

reduce = %Q{
  function(key, values) {   
    var total_commission = 0; 
    values.forEach(function(value) {
      total_commission += value.total_commission; // to sum 
    });        
    return {total_count: values.length, total_commission: total_commission, uniq_commission: values[0]["total_commission"]};
  }
}
```

output like:

```
[
{"_id":{"ip":"39.49.65.101","campaign_id":{"$oid":"548121156e6f62101f000000"}},"value":   {"total_count":1.0,"total_commission":1.0,"uniq_commission":0.0}},

{"_id":{"ip":"39.49.65.102","campaign_id":{"$oid":"548121156e6f62101f000000"}},"value":{"total_count":5.0,"total_commission":1.0,"uniq_commission":0.0}},

{"_id":{"ip":"39.49.65.103","campaign_id":{"$oid":"548121156e6f62101f000000"}},"value":{"total_count":3.0,"total_commission":1.0,"uniq_commission":0.0}},

...
]
```

I want calculate like this:

```
result = {}
obj.map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true).each do |r|
   result["total_count"] += r["value"]["total_count"]
   result["total_commission"] += r["value"]["total_commission"]
   result["uniq_count"] += 1 
   result["uniq_commission"] += r["value"]["uniq_commission"]
end
```

This function take a long time to calculate with big database
**50.000 record ~ 40s**

Any solution for this case?
I wish I can access some global obj to handle this ^_^

**EDIT:**
SOme data example:

```
<Transaction _id: 5491a66e6e6f620ff4f74d00, commission: 1.0, total_cost: 200.0, order_id: "Order-1418831470", ip: "11.11.11.11", referer_url: nil, campaign_id: BSON::ObjectId('548121156e6f62101f000000'), affiliate_id: BSON::ObjectId('5472dea46e6f62236c060000'), rawclick_id: BSON::ObjectId('5491a66e6e6f620ff4f64d00'), _keywords: ["123213", "abc", "company", "last", "name", "organization"]> 


<Transaction _id: 5491a66e6e6f620ff4f74d11, commission: 1.0, total_cost: 200.0, order_id: "Order-1418831470", ip: "11.11.11.11", referer_url: nil, campaign_id: BSON::ObjectId('548121156e6f62101f000000'), affiliate_id: BSON::ObjectId('5472dea46e6f62236c060000'), rawclick_id: BSON::ObjectId('5491a66e6e6f620ff4f64d00'), _keywords: ["123213", "abc", "company", "last", "name", "organization"]> 


<Transaction _id: 5491a66e6e6f620ff4f74d22, commission: 1.0, total_cost: 200.0, order_id: "Order-1418831470", ip: "22.22.22.22", referer_url: nil, campaign_id: BSON::ObjectId('548121156e6f62101f000000'), affiliate_id: BSON::ObjectId('5472dea46e6f62236c060000'), rawclick_id: BSON::ObjectId('5491a66e6e6f620ff4f64d00'), _keywords: ["123213", "abc", "company", "last", "name", "organization"]> 


<Transaction _id: 5491a66e6e6f620ff4f74d33, commission: 1.0, total_cost: 200.0, order_id: "Order-1418831470", ip: "33.33.33.33", referer_url: nil, campaign_id: BSON::ObjectId('548121156e6f62101f000000'), affiliate_id: BSON::ObjectId('5472dea46e6f62236c060000'), rawclick_id: BSON::ObjectId('5491a66e6e6f620ff4f64d00'), _keywords: ["123213", "abc", "company", "last", "name", "organization"]> 


<Transaction _id: 5491a66e6e6f620ff4f74d44, commission: 1.0, total_cost: 200.0, order_id: "Order-1418831470", ip: "96.9.32.51", referer_url: nil, campaign_id: BSON::ObjectId('548121156e6f62101f000000'), affiliate_id: BSON::ObjectId('5472dea46e6f62236c060000'), rawclick_id: BSON::ObjectId('5491a66e6e6f620ff4f64d00'), _keywords: ["123213", "abc", "company", "last", "name", "organization"]>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example input dataset (like 5 rows)? You should `index` your data first then run mapreduce or aggregation - depends on the nature of the data and if you're doing it on a single/multiple computers.

Comment: I have some edit below.
If I use sub mapreduce is it lower?
And pLease help me find out this syntax

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538524/mongoid-syntax-to-call-sub-mapreduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've read your map/reduce correctly, all that you are doing is computing the number and total commission of your documents grouped by `ip` and `campaign_id`. I'm not sure what the purpose of `uniq_commission` is supposed to be, as, in your map/reduce, its final value depends on how MongoDB executes the map/reduce and, in the other code, it's always zero since it sums up values that seem like they are all set to zero. - if you can explain it's purpose I'll attempt to modify my answer to take it into account. Don't use map/reduce. Aggregation can do this calculation, and will do it faster than map/reduce:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$group" : { "_id" : { "ip" : "$ip", "campaign_id" : "$campaign_id" },
                   "total_count" : { "$sum" : 1 },
                   "total_commission" : { "$sum" : "$commission" }
    } }
])
```

Comment: Yes, Same at your way. I do it with aggregate container 2 group. And it work well. Time cost is so amazing :). Thanks for your answer