# mongoid, syntax to call sub mapreduce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/unique_items_map_reduce/
how can I access with sub mapreduce like this.
I try some way :

```
Transaction.all.limit(10).map_reduce(map, reduce).out(replace: 'mr_result').map_reduce(map1, reduce1).out(inline: true).raw

Transaction.all.limit(10).map_reduce(map, reduce).map_reduce(map1, reduce1).out(inline: true).raw
```

the result fail:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `map_reduce' for #<Mongoid::Contextual::MapReduce:0x007f58424cc4e8>
```

Comment: The cookbook entry you link to does an MR into a collection and then MR's that intermediate collection. You'd do the same thing here but you'd probably go through Moped to work with the intermediate collection since you probably don't have a model for it. You could probably use the aggregation framework depending on what your MRs are doing.

Comment: I have some group and calculating, aggregation not enough to do.
And I have new question. please visit here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539387/mongoid-mongodb-mapreduce-get-scope-varriable-or-pass-it-to-output