# mongoid - mongodb, mapreduce get scope varriable or pass it to output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query

In mapreduce I have a scope total_count to calculate something after grouping something.
How can I get back the that scope varriable in output?

**EDIT:**

```
 map = %Q{
      function() {  
        ttotal_commission += this.commission;
        tuniq_commission += this.commission; // add first if it not goto reduce
        emit({ip: this.ip, campaign_id: this.campaign_id}, {commission: this.commission, abc: this.commission});
      }
    }

    reduce = %Q{
      function(key, values) {  
        tuniq_commission += values[0].commission; // add 1 and substract laster for uniq

        var total_commission = 0;
        values.forEach(function(value) {    
          tuniq_commission -= value.commission;
          total_commission += value.commission;
        });         
        return {};
      }
    }

    final = %Q{
      function(key, reduceVal){
        reduceVal.ttotal_commission = ttotal_commission;
        reduceVal.tuniq_commission = tuniq_commission;  
        return reduceVal;
      }
    }


temp = Transaction.all.limit(45000).map_reduce(map, reduce).scope(ttotal_commission: 0, tuniq_commission: 0).finalize(final).out(inline: true).first
```

Comment: Write a `finalize` function and return the scope variable in the reduced object. For more help please post the code you have written so far.

Comment: Yes It work. but query still slow. I Just group and count. WHy it take so long time? Is it slow because raw the results. I have 45.000 record
and it take me ~15s. I have index before

Comment: The performance of your code can be monitored better when you actually post what you have done. Kindly edit your question with the code you have written.

Comment: I included code. Please see this

Comment: COuld Sub mapreduce improve performance? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538524/mongoid-syntax-to-call-sub-mapreduce

Comment: Thanks for posting the code.Some observations made: A reduce function which returns an empty object {}, is useless. Because what it does is simply update a global value, based on the grouped records. It also indicates that you don't have a need to go for a map reduce approach. You should have gone for the aggregation framework with a single `$group` with a `$sum` operator to calculate the total. Further you could use the operators such as `$subtract`, `$add` to manipulate data. If map reduce is not a must then aggregation would improve the performance.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do this query. I not work well with it ^_^

Comment: Final I work it out. thanks for helpful advice :D